# How to update without replacing subdocument array in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how to update a subdocument array without replacing the previous data in mongodb, i tried this below but it is replacing the previous data

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d2d8deff4e6c1d71fc29a07"),
    "name" : "crystal",
      "events" : [
        {
          "handled": 12,
          "profile": 10,
          "data": "....."
        }

      ]
}
```

this below is the query

```
db.getCollection('Shows').update({ name: "crystal" }, {$set: { events: events }})
```

i would like to instead get this result below when updating, keeping the previous data but add new data

```
const events = {
   "handled": 14,
   "profile": 12,
    "data": "....."
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d2d8deff4e6c1d71fc29a07"),
    "name" : "crystal",
      "events" : [
        {
          "handled": 12,
          "profile": 10,
          "data": "....."
        }
          {
          "handled": 14,
          "profile": 12,
          "data": "....."
        }

      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('Shows').update({ name: "crystal" }, {$push: { events: req.body.events }})
```

Use push insted of $set

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
db.getCollection('Shows').updateOne(
 { name: "crystal" },
 {$push: { 'events': {"handled": 14,
          "profile": 12,
          "data": "....." } }}

)
```

Comment: But i am too late